# Symfony/Doctrine: "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class <type> could not be converted to string" when persisting

Tags: annotations, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

A symfony2 application has a `Job` entity that has as a property of type `WebSite`.

A simplified representation of this without other properties or methods:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Job")
 */
class Job
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="website_id", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Example\ExampleBundle\Entity\WebSite")
     */
    protected $website;
}
```

Symfony/Doctrine is trying to cast the `website` property to a string when persisting resulting in the error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   Example\ExampleBundle\Entity\WebSite could not be converted to string
>   in /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 131

I believe the above @ORM\Column annotation denotes the `website` property to be an integer. I don't understand why Symfony/Doctrine wishes to try and convert the `website` property to a string.

Non-ideal workarounds I have tried in an attempt to resolve the matter:

- Adding `__toString()` method to `WebSite`, returning a string representation of the `id` property, causes the correct value to ultimately end up in the `Job.website_id` datafield; this workaround is impractical as I will in the future need `__toString()` to be available to present a string elsewhere in the application.
- Removing the `@ORM\Column` annotation from the `website` property; this results in all future diff-generated migrations (php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff) removing the 'not null' aspect of the relevant database field.

Are there any changes I should make to the above annotation to inform Symfony/Doctrine to call the `getId()` method of `WebSite` to get what it needs when persisting? Are there any changes I could make to `WebSite` to achieve the same?

What changes are required to ensure that the above annotation can remain in place such that Doctrine ultimately calls `WebSite.getId()` to get what it needs when persisting instead of trying to cast the object to a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remove the `@ORM\Column(type="integer"` annotation from the `$website` property.

To be sure that the website_id column keeps the `NOT NULL` constraint, add a `JoinColumn` annotation with `nullable=false` in it:

```
/**
 * @var Example\ExampleBundle\Entity\WebSite
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Example\ExampleBundle\Entity\WebSite")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="website_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $website;
```

Comment: Note that you have to remove the complete @ORM\Column property from your annotation!